# Error with virtual clone method

Tags: c++, class, oop, virtual-functions

I'm making a header which defines some classes with virtual copy constructors, the code is following:

```
 #ifndef PAYOFF_H
    #define PAYOFF_H

    class Pay_Off{
       public:
      // enum Option_Type {call, put};
       Pay_Off(/*double Strike_, Option_Type Option_*/){};
       virtual double operator()(double Spot) const=0;
       virtual ~Pay_Off(){}
      virtual  Pay_Off* clone() const=0;
      private:
   };

  class Pay_Off_Call: public Pay_Off{
    public:
      Pay_Off_Call(double Strike_);
      virtual double operator()(double Spot) const;
      virtual Pay_Off* clone() const;
      virtual ~Pay_Off_Call(){}
    private:
      double Strike;
  };

  class Pay_Off_Put:public Pay_Off{
    public:
      Pay_Off_Put(double Strike_);
      virtual double operator()(double Spot) const;
      virtual Pay_Off* clone const;
      virtual ~Pay_Off_Put(){}
    private:
      double Strike;
  };
  #endif
```

And when compiling it keeps on poping out the error:

```
error: ‘clone’ declared as a ‘virtual’ field
     virtual Pay_Off* clone const;
```

I don't have an understanding about why it happens, how can I fix it?

Comment: Looks like you forgot `()` after `clone`.

Comment: I wouldn't call that a copy-constructor. It's simply a virtual member function that returns a pointer to a copy of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `virtual Pay_Off* clone const;` with `virtual Pay_Off* clone() const;` And it will compile.

Answer (score 0):

In class `Pay_Off_Put`

```
virtual Pay_Off* clone const;
```

Here you missed `()` in method declaration. Without it, compiler treats it as a *member variable*, which can not be virtual. Hence it shown this error.

Declare it as

```
virtual Pay_Off* clone() const;
```